# PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ']' on line 1

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I used below statement to enter data in a table 'songs' using php artisan tinker in command prompt but it is showing `PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ']' on line 1`.

```
DB::table('songs')->insert(['title'->'Closer','artist'->'chainsmokers','created_at'->new DateTime,'updated_at'->new DateTime ]);
```

Comment: The thing inside the `insert()` is an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func).

Answer (score 2):

Use `=>` instead of `->`

```
DB::table('songs')->insert([
    'title' => 'Closer',
    'artist' => 'chainsmokers',
    'created_at' => new DateTime,
    'updated_at' => new DateTime,
]);
```